# Drag & Drop with PHP & jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have used the following code found [here](http://papermashup.com/drag-drop-with-php-jquery) on a page I am developing and all is working fine.

I would however, like to be able to pull mulitple columns from my database and have them formatted on a table.

I have tried everything and cannot get this to work. Should I be using HTML tables or something else? The code below just displays all columns as one long unformatted row.

```
<div id="container">

<div id="list">

<ul>

<?php
include("connect.php");
$query  = "SELECT id, listorder, description, owner, perc_complete, start_date, end_date FROM acct_project_details WHERE project_id='1' ORDER BY listorder ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$id = stripslashes($row['id']);
$listorder = stripslashes($row['listorder']);
$text = stripslashes($row['description']);
$owner = stripslashes($row['owner']);
$perc_complete = stripslashes($row['perc_complete']);
$start_date = stripslashes($row['start_date']);
$end_date = stripslashes($row['end_date']);

?>

<li id="arrayorder_<?php echo $id ?>">


<?php echo $text; ?>
<?php echo $owner; ?>
<?php echo $perc_complete; ?>
<?php echo $start_date; ?>
<?php echo $end_date; ?>

<div class="clear"></div>
</li>

<?php } ?>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 0):

Use `table tr  td` and [TableDnD](https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/tree/master/stable) plugin :

```
<!-- DOWNLOAD THESE SCRIPTS -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://isocra.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.10.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://isocra.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.2.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/blob/master/stable/jquery.tablednd.js'></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("table.dnd").tableDnD();
});
</script>

<div id="container">

<div id="list">

<table class="dnd">

<?php
include("connect.php");
$query  = "SELECT id, listorder, description, owner, perc_complete, start_date, end_date FROM acct_project_details WHERE project_id='1' ORDER BY listorder ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

$id = stripslashes($row['id']);
$listorder = stripslashes($row['listorder']);
$text = stripslashes($row['description']);
$owner = stripslashes($row['owner']);
$perc_complete = stripslashes($row['perc_complete']);
$start_date = stripslashes($row['start_date']);
$end_date = stripslashes($row['end_date']);

?>

<tr id="arrayorder_<?php echo $id ?>">


<td><?php echo $text; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $owner; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $perc_complete; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $start_date; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $end_date; ?></td>

</tr>

<?php } ?>

</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @kmas - this has formatted the table but now I am unable to move the rows up and down - any ideas? Thanks John

Comment: Use this plugin if you want to do so : https://github.com/isocra/TableDnD/tree/master/stable . Here is an example : http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/ (See my edited post)

Comment: Thanks @kmas, this looks great. I will need some pointers on how to get this to update my MySQL db table, can you help? Thanks John

Comment: If you want to do these kind of things, I would tell you to use `jQgrid` plugin that does everything you need and even more : see the demo http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html It is very popular and works very well. The only things is that it has to be feeded with JSON (`json_encode` function with php) : drag and drop, pagination, lazyload, edition, deletion, search... Well a lot of things.

Comment: Or you can add a button for each row with an url (edit_row.php?id=<?php echo $id ?> ) to edit this row. Well there are so many options that I cannot help you more.

Comment: I am specificaly looking for the drag and drop functionality to re-order rows but I need to display and format multi columns. Thanks for your help @kmas